# How to check if a function returns one type of data or another in python

Tags: python

I have a function that must return lists, however if it is not possible to convert correctly in the try that is shown, then it means that the input is wrong, and what I do is return false here the code:

```
def objective_function(fo):
    min_or_max = 0
    piso = 5
    i = 5
    C = []
    index = []
    if fo[0 : 5] == "minz=":
        min_or_max = 1
    elif fo[0 : 5] == "maxz=":
        min_or_max = 2
    while i < len(term):
        if fo[i] == "+" or fo[i] == "-":
            coefficient, j = separate_term(fo[piso : i])
            try:
                C.append(Fr(coefficient))
                index.append(int(j))
            except:
                return False
            piso = i
    print(C)
    return min_or_max, C
```

**What I want to do is know if it returns false to make a print ("It has an error"), and if not show the two lists that it returns as I would do it?**

Comment: You haven't shown how this function is being used, but you could just check for truthiness: `ret = objective_function(data); if ret: print("All good") else print("Error")`.

Comment: Are you trying to check the data type of an object? This might help
[isinstance](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_isinstance.asp)

Comment: If the function must return a list, raise an exception if you cannot do so. This forces your caller to deal with the failure, rather than allowing it to incorrectly assume the return value is a list.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is the part in which I call the function and check that it returns, regardless of what I send it, I send it a string and if everything goes well it returns two lists, and if something goes wrong I get returns a False

Comment: @chepner The try works, however in this case it does not check if it is a False, only an error occurs before and it is passed to the exception, is this the best way? Is there no other?

Comment: I'm saying, if something goes wrong, raise an exception *instead* of returning `False`. Otherwise, your caller can mistakenly try to use `False` in a context where they need the expected return value, and they'll get a new error anyway.

Comment: I need to generate a string for other mandatory purposes. @chepner